# SQL Server handshake timeout error at the pre-login

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sqlclient

I'm running VS 2015 and SQL Server 2008 R2 on a remote server.

When I try to connect to my database via SSMS, everything is fine. When I try to connect via Visual Studio Server Explorer, it also works fine, but when I do it through C# `SqlClient`, it times-out.

I'm always using integrated security.

Everything is running fine on my colleagues computer.

What can cause that? How can I debug it?

Error message :

> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=1879; handshake=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply deleted thee solution and re imported it from  our version control and it worked (rebooting wasn't enough)